# Custom view get custom attribute value from custom theme attribute in Android

Tags: android, android-view

The probleam is this.
I have a custom view, named `CustomedView`, and define a custom view attribute named `myTintColor`, so I can use my custom view in XML and define its attribute with custom attribute `myTintColor`。

the code like this:

```
<CustomedView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:myTintColor="@color/color1"
/>

// in kotlin or java code
val a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomedView)
val colorResId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomedView_myTintColor, 0)
val myTintColor = context.getColor(colorResId)
a.recycle()
```

the above is be knwon by anyone, and work well. now, if I define a **theme attribute** like this

```
<resources>
    <attr name="myBackgroundColor" format="color" />
</resources>
```

and, use this attribute to indicate custom view's myTintColor

```
<CustomedView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:myTintColor="?attr/myBackgroundColor"
/>
```

so, the problem is now, how to get the color from custom attribute?

my code is:

```
val a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomedView)
val attrId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomedView_myTintColor, 0)
val typedValue = TypedValue()
context.theme.resolveAttribute(attrId, typedValue, true)
val myTintColor = typedValue.data // but this value is always 0.
a.recycle()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your custom attribute `myBackgroundColor` still references the color.

```
val color = a.getColor(R.styleable.CustomedView_myBackgroundColor, resources.getColor(R.color.defaultColor))
textView.setTextColor(color)
```